# Entity Framework Core - retrieving shadow properties from a linked table using dependency Injection and not "context"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I note there are a number of places that use the code structure below:

```
context.Entry(Notes).Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
```

I am using the repository pattern for better or worse and I use dependency injection to access the records. In particular, I `loadRelatedEntities` (lazy loading) to access the notes information on the client record.

Here is the client entity:

```
public class Client : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
{
    public Client()
    {
        Jobs = new List<Job>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ClientNo { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? ClientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ClientLastName { get; set; } = default!;

    public virtual ICollection<Note>? Notes { get; }
}
```

My `Note` entity is as follows:

```
public class Note : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
{
    #nullable enable
    public Note()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Details { get; set; }

    public int? JobId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job? Job { get; set; }

    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client? Client { get; set; }

    public int? NoteTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual NoteType NoteType { get; set; }
}
```

In my client repository I have the following:

```
public class ClientDATARepository : EntityBaseDATARepository<Client>, IClientDATARepository
{
    private readonly DATAContext _context;

    public ClientDATARepository(DATAContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void RelatedClientEntities(Client client)
    {
        _context.Entry(client).Reference(j => j.Notes).Load();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** here is my Notes Repository:

```
using JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES;
using JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces;

namespace JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories
{
    public class NoteDATARepository : EntityBaseDATARepository<Note>, INoteDATARepository
    {
        public NoteDATARepository(DATAContext context) : base(context) { }
    }
}
```

I use "context" in the repository and use dependency injection to access the data in the related class, in this case `ClientServices`.

```
public class ClientServices : IClientServices 
{
        IClientDATARepository clientDATARepository,

        public ClientServices(IClientDATARepository clientDATARepository,
        {
            ClientDATARepository = clientDATARepository;
        }
}
```

So in that class that has used dependency injection to load the client repository; I ,as a result, have a client that has the related entities loaded, in particular, "Notes".

```
ClientDATARepository.RelatedClientEntities(client);
```

So if I go say:

```
var noteModel = client.notes
```

and examine notes I only get the entity properties that were set up in the entity and no shadow properties.

I also note I can't use

```
context.Entry(Notes).Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
```

because I don't have access to context...

So given I am using a repository to obtain the client, in this case, and not context directly, how do I access those shadow properties of the notes linked to the client?

Comment: So, you've hidden the context in `IClientDATARepository`, which provides access to load related data? Why not extend that interface to access shadow properties too?

Comment: It would appear you are across this.. How might I do this..

Comment: I've added my Notes Repository for the purpose of adding in shadow properties under UPDATE...